# Strings in Array/List in for loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So my Array contains this data

```
Abonnenten = ["https://www.instagram.com/vivksj/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/aaalink/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/haanannnnna/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/tiigergirlxofical/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/patriiciaa.015/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/itss_leonie_/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/patriciawk/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/taelly.scr/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/mozzhliana/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/mialecdron/"]
```

Because of data protection i changed the usernames, but you get the example.
In my code i want to browse through a few selected users of instagram. If they have their snapchat linked in their bio like so:

[Snapchat Name Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgaeb.png)

[Snapchat Name Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jq7r.png)

```
for i in range(len(Abonnenten)):
driver.get(Abonnenten[i])
# get the text from their instagram bio
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text
    Snapnames = list.append(bio)
    print(Snapnames)
```

Here i wanted to try to get all the snapchat names my app found to print out. But i couldn´t figure out that.

```
 # check if text contains "snapchat"
    if ("snapchat" in bio):

        # split the instagram bio by newline char to get line with snapchat name
        bio_lines = bio.split("\n")

        # parse over the instagram bio to find snapchat username
        for line in bio_lines:

            # if we find the line with username, strip out text to get the username
            if ("Snapchat:" in line):
                #snapchat_username = []
                snapchat_username = line.replace[("Snapchat:", "")]
                # you probably need to do something here to save to file
                print(snapchat_username)
```

Although those code lines are commented i can´t figure out what they do or if they work.

```
        # case: the user does not have a bio, so just move on to the next one
except TimeoutException:
    continue
i = i + 1
```

the last lines of code should be self explaining.
Once again, i want to **scrape** a instagram users bio for his/her snapchat name and if they have one it saves it to a list or array so i can either give it out as a file or print it out. (i use the chromedriver)

Comment: `Abonnenten` should be renamed to `abonnenten`, eh. As far as I can tell, The code only searches for the text ‘Snapchat:’, but even your username examples show that there are many different pieces of text that could indicate a username. Is that normal?

Comment: Also, could you share more of your code? It’ll make it easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah i want to make multiple queries to have a larger "win-rate", and that is literally all of my code

Comment: What do you mean by _win-rate_, exactly?

Comment: When i just search for Snapchat in a bio there is a high chance the person put their Snapchat name in like: "sc" or "snap" or " so adding more searches for a query i get a higher chance of finding the name

Comment: Right, that was my best guess, I was just thrown off by the expression _win-rate_. If I understand correctly, you're looking for help understanding this code? Would you open to a refactored version, if it were clearer?

Comment: I need a code that works. I can get through users but dont get their snapchat of their bio. And a list where i could save the names if it would work.

Comment: Do you just need the bio, or are you required to use Selenium for something else?

Comment: Was my answer enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started, it creates a list of usernames and their associated bio.

```py
import requests

profile_links = ["https://www.instagram.com/vivksj/", 
                 "https://www.instagram.com/aaalink/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/haanannnnna/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/tiigergirlxofical/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/patriiciaa.015/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/itss_leonie_/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/patriciawk/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/taelly.scr/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/mozzhliana/",
                 "https://www.instagram.com/mialecdron/"]

profile_data_list = []

for curr_profile_url in profile_links:
    req_res = requests.get(curr_profile_url + '?__a=1')
    if req_res.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Error status code {req_res.status_code} for url {curr_profile_url}')
    else:
        json_res = req_res.json()
        json_user_portion = json_res['graphql']['user']
        username = json_user_portion['username']
        profile_data_list.append((username, json_user_portion))

profile_bio_list = [(curr_username, curr_data['biography']) for curr_username, curr_data in profile_data_list]
```

`profile_bio_list` looks like this:

```
[('vivksj',
  "I just don't walk on the clouds of my dreams,I turn them into reality..."),
 ('aaalink', ''),
 ('itss_leonie_',
  '❤️14 y/o❤️\n'
  '15.8 B-day❤️\n'
  '@itss_celia_ ❤️\n'
  '@itss_maria_4 ❤️\n'
  '@leonie__prv_'),
 ('patriciawk', '')]
```